# How do I make an INNER JOIN properly

Tags: sql, database, inner-join

I have 2 tables, im looking for a number associated with an id from another table.
I've hit a snag and can't figure it out.

there is no error, it just takes for-ever then times out :(

my tables are as follows;

table 'trips' has the following columns;
route_id,trip_id

table 'stop_times' has;
trip_id,departure_time,stop_id

I have stop_id, but need to view all records with that stop_id but also need to be able to only select ones that match the route_id

here is my best effort at making the sql;

```
SELECT stop_times.trip_id, stop_times.departure_time, stop_times.stop_id, trips.trip_id, trips.route_id FROM stop_times
WHERE trips.route_id = 23
INNER JOIN trips ON stop_times.trip_id=trips.trip_id
ORDER BY stop_times.departure_time ASC
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong order. `WHERE` comes after `JOIN`:

```
SELECT stop_times.trip_id, stop_times.departure_time, stop_times.stop_id, trips.trip_id, trips.route_id 
FROM stop_times
INNER JOIN trips ON stop_times.trip_id=trips.trip_id
WHERE trips.route_id = 23
ORDER BY stop_times.departure_time ASC
```